# Putting Nested Classes In Separate Files

Tags: java, nested-class

I have a file with nested classes, but it's becoming long enough to be unreadable. Is there a way I can break out the nested classes into separate files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the right tools.

[image]

Comment: NetBeans: Right click class -> Refractor -> Move Inner to Outer Level

Comment: ...although technically this isn't what I asked for (as Nikita pointed out), this is in fact what I wanted.

Comment: Or press F6 when your cursor is over the class name in IDEA, which is the right tool.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not.
As an alternative, you could consider converting some of them to plain Java classes: although nested classes increase encapsulation, you can certainly create good OO design without them.

My two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Write unit-tests to cover the code you are going to refactor.

Then use refactoring tools, e.g. Eclipse/JDT to extract each class. Run the tests for each refactoring job.

For extra fun, you can do this without the unit tests.