# Declaring nested classes in separate files

Tags: java, nested-class

Here we have a nested class:

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        ...
    }

}
```

Instead of writing them in the same file, can I declare them in separate files?

This question: [Putting Nested Classes In Separate Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645047/putting-nested-classes-in-separate-files) tells me to use a refactor option that happens to be available in Eclipse. I use it, but I end up with two files:

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
}
```

and

```
class StaticNestedClass {

}
```

But as far as I'm concerned, that's no longer a nested class, right?

Comment: I mean ... word "Nested" kinda answers this.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I don't see a reason why would that mean I can't declare a nested class in another file. I mean, it's just another file. The compiler could say *"welp, I'm gonna grab the class in that file and pretend it is nested inside this other one"*. Simply to make the project look more organized. Like C++, or Ruby, dunno.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting Nested Classes In Separate Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645047/putting-nested-classes-in-separate-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in Java.

As a note, if you were using a language that supports partial classes (such as C#) you could do

File 1:

```
partial class OuterClass {
}
```

File 2:

```
partial class OuterClass {
    class StaticNestedClass {

    }
}
```

but Java doesn't have partial classes so this wouldn't be of help for this particular situation. In Java a class can only be declared in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Nested class is a class that's literally INSIDE another class. No, it's not possible to have a nested class in a separate file because then it would no longer be a nested class, it would be just another class.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot have them in separate source files using javac as a compiler.